# How to get under the ring and use the tables, ladders and chairs?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wwe-13

My son has come to a frustrating part in the WWE13 game on the Wii. He is unable to get under the ring and reach for tables, ladders, and chairs. What buttons to need to be pressed to get through this stage?

Answer (score 1):

He has to push the <kbd>z</kbd> button on the nunchuck.

Comment: But I do that and when I go under and select the item nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

You press Z, and to pick the item use the nunchuck, and A to select.